# Simple HangMan game Implemented in Java

Tags: java, hangman

This simple implementation of the HangMan game in Java is a side project, unlike the usual programs I write which are either school assignments or problems on coding websites.

It feels great to have something simple working, but I know for sure this can be improved. This only runs through the command line now, but I'm thinking of adding a lot more to this in the near future.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner userGuess = new Scanner(System.in);

        printTitleScreen();
        System.out.println("");
        String word = getRandomWordFromFile("/Users/kingcold/Desktop/words.txt");
        char[] wordCharArray = word.toCharArray();

        System.out.println("It's time to guess the word!");

        StringBuilder gameWord = new StringBuilder(printBlankSpaces(word));

        int successfulAttempts = 0;
        int failedAttempts = 0;
        int totalAttempts = 0;


        do {

            System.out.println("Your word looks like this: " + gameWord);
            System.out.println("Your guess: ");

            String userInput = userGuess.next();
            char charUserInput = userInput.charAt(0);

            if (isValidInput(userInput)) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is: " + userInput);

                    if (!(containsUserInput(wordCharArray, userInput))) {

                        letterNotInWordMessage(userInput);
                        failedAttempts++;

                    } else if (containsUserInput(wordCharArray, userInput)){

                        letterInWordMessage(userInput);     
                        gameWord.setCharAt(getMatchingIndex(wordCharArray, userInput), charUserInput);
                        successfulAttempts++;

                    }

            } else {

                System.out.println("Invalid input entered. Try again.");

            }

            totalAttempts = successfulAttempts + failedAttempts;


        } while (!word.equals(gameWord.toString()));


        if (word.equals(gameWord.toString())) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations, you correctly guessed the word!");
            System.out.println("The word is " + word);
            System.out.println("You guessed the word in " + totalAttempts + " attempts");
            userGuess.close();
        }

    }

    private static void printTitleScreen() {
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman!");
        System.out.println("-------------------");
    }

    private static String printBlankSpaces(String word) {
        return new String(new char[word.length()]).replace('\0', '-');
    }

    private static void letterNotInWordMessage(String letter) {
        System.out.println("The letter " + letter + " is not in the word!");
    }

    private static void letterInWordMessage(String letter) {
        System.out.println("The letter " + letter + " is in the word!");
    }

    private static int getMatchingIndex(char[] wordArray, String userGuess) {
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < wordArray.length && (index == -1); i++) {
            if (String.valueOf(wordArray[i]).equals(userGuess)) {
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    private static boolean containsUserInput(char[] wordArray, String userGuess) {
        for (int i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
            if (wordArray[i] == userGuess.charAt(0)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean isValidInput(String userGuess) {
        final int VALID_INPUT_LENGTH = 1;
        if (userGuess.length() == VALID_INPUT_LENGTH  && Character.isLetter(userGuess.charAt(0))) {
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }

    private static String getRandomWordFromFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
        String fileContents = "";

        while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            fileContents = fileContents.concat(fileScanner.nextLine() + "\n");
        }

        fileScanner.close();
        String[] fileContentArray = fileContents.split("\n");
        return fileContentArray[(int) (Math.random() * fileContentArray.length)];

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let’s start with your utility methods.

---

#### `printBlankSpaces(String word)`

This method returns a new `String`; It does not do any printing.  It needs a better name...

---

#### `getMatchingIndex(char[] wordArray, String userInput)`

You repeatedly turn each character of `wordArray[]` into a `String` using `String.valueOf(...)`.  It would be better to turn the `userInput` into a character before the loop starts (using `.charAt(0)`), and just do a simple comparison in the loop with that character.

It would be even better to pass in a `char userInput`, instead of a `String`.

Instead of `&& (index == -1)` in your loop condition, just `break;` out of the loop after you do the assignment `index = i;`, or even simplier, `return i;` and you could remove the `index` variable entirely.

---

#### `containsUserInput(char[] wordArray, String userInput)`

Instead of extracting `.charAt(0)` in every iteration of the loop, do it before the start of the loop and save it in a local variable.  Or even better, like above, pass in `char userInput`.

You aren’t using the loop index other than for retrieving the character `wordArray[i]`.  This is a sign you could use an enhanced for-loop:

```
char userChar = userInput.charAt(0);
for (char letter : wordArray) {
   if (letter == userChar) {
       return true;
   }
}
return false;
```

Or even simpler, the entire method could be one statement, leveraging the function above:

```
return getMatchingIndex(wordArray, userInput) >= 0;
```

---

#### `isValidInput(String userGuess)`

The construct `if (condition) return true; else return false;` can be re-written as `return condition;`.  You don’t need the `if` statement.

---

#### `getRandomWordFromFile(String fileName)`

You are doing a lot of work to get a random line from the file.  First, you are reading the file, line-by-line.  Then, you concatenate all the lines together!  Finally you split the concatenation back into the individual lines!

If you simply stored each line as you read it into a `List<String>`, you would be able to skip the concatenation and wouldn’t need to split later.

In fact, reading all the lines of a file into a `List<String>` is such a common operation, there is a standard method for it.  [`List<String> Files.readAllLines(Path path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path)).

With that, the function could be reduced to two lines:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));
return lines[ ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(lines.size()) ];
```

That skips over a lot of fine points.  Most important is ensuring all file resources are properly closed, even in the face of exceptions.  The “try-with-resources” statement is best used for that:

```
File file = new File(fileName);
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        lines.add( scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

All that is done for you with the one `readAllLines()` call.

---

#### main

`charUserInput` is not used.  As mentioned above, many of your methods would be easier to write if they were given a single character, instead of a `String` ... and you have this unused character variable that would be perfect for that...

You tests `if (!(containsUserInput(wordArray, userInput))) { ... }` followed immediately by `else if (containsUserInput(wordArray, userInput)) { ... }`.  Those tests conditions are - literally - opposites of each other; if one is `true`, the other must be `false`, and vis-versa.  Instead of repeating the test, both in code and in CPU time, just use an `else`

```
if (!containsUserInput(wordArray, userInput)) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

I’ve removed the unnecessary ( )’s.  You can improve this further by switching the order of the  then-else clauses, and removing the `!` operator.

```
if (containsUserInput(wordArray, userInput)) {
    ... guess is correct code ...
} else {
    ... guess is incorrect code ...
}
```

Comment: Such a good answer, except for the last sentence suggesting `snake_case` for local variables. The naming conventions say these variables are also written in `camelCase`.

Comment: Upvoted for all the good advice, but I want to explicitly state that I have the same gripe with this answer as Roland does...

Comment: Ok ... ok ... there is a badge for caving in to peer pressure, right?  I’ll remove last sentence.